# Use single logger instance for all rules in drl file

Tags: log4j, drools

I am performing logging from drl file using log4j. I create a separate instance of logger for each rule in drl file. Is there a way to create a single instance of logger that can be used in all the rules defined in drl file.

Answer (score 3):

By making a global in your *.drl:

```
global Logger logger;
```

And doing in *.java:

```
kSession.setGlobal("logger", myLogger);
```

Comment: I think we need the full namespace:
global org.slf4j.Logger logger;